# Get all terms assigned to a post from different taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

There are different taxonomies. I have assigned different tags from these taxonomies to different posts. Can anyone help me to get all the terms which are assigned to a post. (Different terms from different taxonomies are assigned to a post)

Comment: What are you already tried to do?

Comment: I have tried get_the_terms() function but it requires taxonomy name. I can not specify any particular taxonomy name because there are multiple taxonomies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress tracks which object types taxonomy applies to. This can be established on taxonomy registration or at some point after, so you shouldn't be trying to do this too early.

The approach would be to retrieve the list of taxonomies for the native `post` type and use it with lower level function, which supports multiple taxonomies:

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, get_object_taxonomies('post') );
```

Of course if you interested in a list of *specific* taxonomies you can just hardcode that as input.